# Send data from linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel

I want to send some data via tcp from my linux kernel module.
I have tried to use some code from  [http://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/tcp-server-send-recv.c](http://www.avrfreaks.net/sites/default/files/tcp-server-send-recv.) , but there are too old code(it used old linux kernel api).
Also, I have tried to understand https://github.com/abysamross/simple-linux-kernel-tcp-client-server/blob/master/network_server.c , but it is too sophisticated for me:)

I want only send some small data to specified ip adress via tcp. How I can do it?

Comment: The module will just send data ? -- The example you point out is an example of a server. If you need to send data, you must check the example of a client.

Comment: Yes, I need a module that only sends data. 
Actual code for the client is difficult to find, I think that is possible to modify server's code.

Comment: Checking the [client example](https://github.com/abysamross/simple-linux-kernel-tcp-client-server/blob/master/network_client.c) in the same project, if you reuse some functions, you must understand and modify the `tcp_client_connect`  function (lines 124-198) only. You can reuse the `sock_create` function to create the connection socket, the `tcp_client_send` to send data and the `tcp_client_receive` to receive a response.

Comment: I tried to do some similar actions, but is but did not succeed.
What I should to do?
1) call sock_create()
2)call tcp_client_send()?

Comment: What problems did you have ? -- That example is for a kernel module. Try to modify the client module only to send the data you want. If it compiles, you can loaded into your running system. You may check the module messages and errors in the kernel log (checking dmesg). If you have problems, you may send another question showing part of the code and the error messages.

Comment: Okay, so I'll do it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155968/discussion-between-jaime-and-djkah11).

Answer (score 5):

Check the [client example](https://github.com/abysamross/simple-linux-kernel-tcp-client-server/blob/master/network_client.c) in the same project. If you can reuse some functions, you must understand and modify the `tcp_client_connect` function (lines 124-198) only. In that module, the `tcp_client_connect` connection creates a connection when the module is loaded, and the `network_client_exit` closes the connection when the module is unloaded.

In the `tcp_client_connect` function:

1. (line 144) It creates a socket

   ```
    struct socket *conn_socket = NULL;

    ret = sock_create(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, &conn_socket);
   ```
2. Then, (lines 153 to 155 ) it creates a destination address

   ```
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;                               /* a socket address */

    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                             /* for internet */
    saddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);                           /* using the port PORT */
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(create_address(destip));  /* and address destip */
   ```
3. (line 157) It uses that address to open the socket (to create the connection)

   ```
    int ret = -1;

    ret = conn_socket->ops->connect(conn_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr\
                   , sizeof(saddr), O_RDWR);     

    /* if it gets a response and it is not "in progress" */
    if(ret && (ret != -EINPROGRESS))
    {
        /* error creating the socket*/
    }
   ```
4. (lines 166 to 168) It sends a message using the socket.

   ```
   int len = 49;
   char reply[len+1];

   memset(&reply, 0, len+1);   /* sets 0s into all the string space */
   strcat(reply, "HOLA");      /* sets the message */

   tcp_client_send(conn_socket, reply, strlen(reply), MSG_DONTWAIT);
   ```
5. (line 170) It waits for a message (for while)

   ```
   DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(recv_wait);

   /* wait for a response or for a timetout */
   wait_event_timeout(recv_wait,\
                   !skb_queue_empty(&conn_socket->sk->sk_receive_queue),\
                                                                   5*HZ);
   ```
6. (lines 180 to 190) It obtains the response.

   ```
   int len = 49;
   char response[len+1];

   /* if something has arrived */
   if(!skb_queue_empty(&conn_socket->sk->sk_receive_queue))
   {
       memset(&response, 0, len+1);
       tcp_client_receive(conn_socket, response, MSG_DONTWAIT);
   }
   ```

In the `network_client_exit` function,

7. (lines 239 to 240) it closes the connection.

   ```
   /* if the socket has been created */
   if(conn_socket != NULL)
   {
           /* relase the socket */
           sock_release(conn_socket);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The waiting code not work, It only wakeup for timeout.

```
DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(recv_wait);
/* wait for a response or for a timetout */
wait_event_timeout(recv_wait,\
            !skb_queue_empty(&conn_socket->sk->sk_receive_queue),\
                                                            5*HZ);
```